# Is it safe to upgrade my kernel?

Tags: kernel

I'm currently running version 14.04. Is it safe to upgrade only kernel to the recently released 3.16?

Comment: you are right... I'll delete this question...

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.kernel.org,  3.16 is still not stable. 
Better try 3.15.8,  the latest  Stable version

Comment: www.kernel.org has a big yellow box with "Latest Stable Kernel: 3.16"

Comment: The OP asking weather to upgrade the kernel in general.